# How to make the scrolling animation on a view

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

So I have this uiscrollerview... each time 5 seconds passes scrollview should move up.

setcontentoffset is working but it doesnt have an animation. like it should move up slowly.

my code below

```
CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(0, newYLocationForScrollView);
```

`[scroll setContentOffset:bottomOffset animated:YES];`

thanks in advance

Comment: How can you scroll ScrollView put code here

Comment: [scrollView setContentOffset:offset animated:YES];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[UIView animationWithDuration0.3f ^(void) {

// code to do the transition

}];
```

[UIView Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html)

```
[scrollView setContentOffset:offset animated:YES];
```

[UIScrollView Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html)

Comment: it doesnt work... [UIView animationWithDuration:0.3f ^(void) {
        [scroll setContentOffset:bottomOffset animated:YES];
        }];

Comment: those were 2 separate options.... you can do one or the other [UIView animationWithDuration0.3f ^(void) {
[scroll setContentOffSet:offSet]; 
}];

or [scrollView setContentOffset:offset animated:YES];

Comment: `[UIView animateWithDuration:1.00f
                          delay:0.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{
                         [scroll setContentOffset:bottomOffset];
                     }
     
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         
                     }];`

Answer (score 3):

The method you are looking for is [`scrollRectToVisible:animated:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIScrollView/scrollRectToVisible%3aanimated%3a).  Without more details I'll have to leave the code to calculate the desired rect up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Use method of  scrollView `scrollRectToVisible:animated:` and give `animated` property to `YES`

**OR**

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:1.2f animations:^{
       /// write code for animation 
  }];
```

Comment: it doesnt work... [UIView animationWithDuration:0.3f ^(void) {
        [scroll setContentOffset:bottomOffset animated:YES];
        }];

Comment: [scroll setContentOffset:bottomOffset animated:YES]; if you use this method with animation "YES" then no need to use other animation bcoZ this method has its own animation :)